# summarize of frequency variables

Tags: r

I have a data frame and now i am looking for summarize count of variables

```
df <-data.frame(aa = c(NA,"bali",NA,"bali","bali",NA),
                    bb = c("can",NA,"can","can",NA,NA),
                    cc = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,"ban",NA),
                    dd = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA))
```

summarize count only for variables have any single value. excluding variables which is greater than 0

```
var count
aa 3
bb 3
cc 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get data in long format, remove `NA` values and then `count` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = everything(), values_drop_na = TRUE) %>%
  count(name)

#  name      n
#  <chr> <int>
#1 aa        3
#2 bb        3
#3 cc        1
```

Comment: also if the cells are blank ...??

Comment: @newcomer If there are blank values that you want to remove you can do that by adding line `filter(value != '')` after `pivot_longer` and before `count`.

Comment: one more thing if i want count of values like
bali  3
can  3
ban  1

Comment: Then instead of `count(name)` you use `count(value)`.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work:

```
> enframe(lapply(df, function(x) table(x, exclude =  c('',NA)))) %>% unnest(value)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  name  value  
  <chr> <table>
1 aa    3      
2 bb    3      
3 cc    1      
> df
    aa   bb   cc dd   ee
1 <NA>  can <NA> NA <NA>
2 bali <NA> <NA> NA     
3 <NA>  can <NA> NA <NA>
4 bali  can <NA> NA     
5 bali <NA>  ban NA <NA>
6 <NA> <NA> <NA> NA <NA>
>
```

Comment: cells also have blank and NA in columns

Comment: @newcomer, have modified my query accordingly, have changed the data you shared by adding blacks in column "ee".